# URL ID undefined in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have an application using angularjs with codeigniter as backend.

In my URL, I have `http://localhost/submit/1234` . `1234` as ID.

In my angularjs

```
var singlepost = angular.module('singlepost', []);


singlepost.controller('singlepostController',function($scope,$http){
     var getSinglePost = function(id){
        $http.get('/post/'+id).success(function(data){
                $scope.posts = data;
                console.log(id);
        }); 
    }
    getSinglePost();

});
```

I want to get the 1234 id so I can send it to backend via `localhost/post/1234` but when I console log `id` I get undefined.

How can I get `1234` ?

Comment: R u passing any id? while calling getSinglePost function

Comment: I am just passing id to $http.get

Comment: Can post some more code? how your function getSinglePost is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `$state` in your `app.js` config get this

```
$stateParams.id
```

if you use `$routeProvider` in your `app.js` congig get this

```
$routeParams.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the id `undefined` because you are not passing parameter id to the function.
I dont know about the whole scenario, but you are defining a function which take id as a parameter. To get the id in function you have to pass one.

```
 getSinglePost(1234);
```

Answer (score 1):

The last thing you do in this controller is call the `getSinglePost()` method, but you don't seem to be passing an `id` to it.

Also, when you figure this out, you really should put the `getSinglePost` method into an Angular service. It's the "Angular Way".

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ngResource
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ngResource/service/$resource